# php fread() strips mail newlines

Tags: php, email, fread

If I fopen/fread a text file, then send the content in an email, the newlines in the text file do not appear in the email when it arrives.

For example, the text...

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, 
consectetur adipiscing elit.         
Sed leo erat, 
rutrum posuere justo.
```

... arrives in the email inbox as:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed leo erat, rutrum posuere justo.
```

I'm using this PHP code:

```
$fh = fopen($email_file,'r');
$message = fread($fh,filesize($email_file));
fclose($fh);
mail("email@example.com",$subject,$message,$headers);
//Assume each variable is declared and defined.
```

What am I missing?

Edit:   I needed to change the header Content-Type from HTML for the text version. Thanks to Yzmir and Footie. Their questions / comments led me to the correct answer.

Comment: When you look at the RAW contents of the email in your email client do you see the new lines?  I believe they should be encoded like `=0A` or something like that if memory serves me right.

Comment: Have you tried using `file()` to read your file into an array and then `explode()` the array with the correct newlines that `mail()` likes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing the new lines with `<br/>` and let me know if this solves it.
If you can't do it for your files, do it in your code using:

```
$message = nl2br($message);
```

Comment: Does `mail()` default to Html type emails?  I could had sworn you had to pass in a header to do that?

Comment: it would usually depend on either the server configuration or the recipient. As sometimes a mail client will only read mail in a html format, others will accept any.

Comment: maybe this is an email client issue as a text email is being displayed as html, thus I see why you suggested adding `<br />` into the message.

Comment: Exactly :) and if it doesn't work, then it's narrowed down the possible things it could be.

Comment: This is what's going on: I have two different versions of email files, one for text, the other for HTML. I neglected to change the header Content-Type from HTML for the text version.

Thanks Yzmir and Footie. Your questions / comments led me to the correct answer.